# General solution of the differential equation $y''-\sin(x)y=0$ given $y(\pi)=1$ and $y'(\pi)=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Does there exist a method to solve this in a "simpler" way than im trying to?
im trying to use the powerseries of sin(x) and show that they are the same. but i end up with a lot of algebra that gets me noway.

also its up to 5 digits in the answer

Comment: CAS can solve. Solution expressed by:`MathieuC`, `MathieuS`,`MathieuCPrime` and `MathieuSPrime`

Comment: How can i write exactly this into CAS? Dont really use CAS. so not sure how to do it

Comment: Maple: https://www.maplesoft.com/products/Maple/students/ code: `dsolve([y(Pi) = 1, D(y)(Pi) = 0, diff(y(x), x, x) - sin(x)*y(x) = 0])`

Comment: anyway you know how i can write this into matlab?

Comment: I don't have matlab :(

Comment: What is exactly the expected solution? In your last sentence it seems to be a numerical solution which is correct to 5 digits. Over what integration interval?

Comment: Well i dont know how to solve it. i want to find the answer up to 5 digits

Comment: But what does it mean "the answer up to 5 digits"? What is the answer, of what are the digits to be counted?

Comment: numerical approximation

Comment: Yeah, but what parameters? It makes a difference if you want 5 digits on [0,10] or on [-1000,1000]. Or just on the period $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: [0,10] would be good!

Comment: You can get that wit `ode45` if you set the tolerances with `odeset` low enough. The standard tolerances are chosen for fast, good plot results, which probably will fall slightly short of the 5 digits accuracy.